# Model:create used once but two rows created (laravel)

Tags: laravel

I was coding in my app and suddenly I realized that every create in my app makes two rows!
whenever I run model:create it makes two rows! it doesn't matter how or when I use a create method.
For example:

```php
Route::get('test', function () {
    \App\City::create([
        'name' => 123,
        'province_id' => 1
    ]);
});
```

obviously such code should create one row. but it creates two! I am stuck and don't know what to do!!

**Update**:
the city model is simple, but it doesn't matter what model I use.
But, running same code during interactive php artisan tinker session creates one row.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class City extends Model
{
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['name' , 'province_id'];

    public function province()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Province');
    }
}
```

Comment: Please show us the City model.

Does it create two if you perform a City::create([]); during an interactive php artisan tinker session?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper
during the interactive php artisan tinker session it creates one!

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper do you have any solution?

Comment: Through tinker you have verified that create([]); works as expected. The problem must come in through the use case. Are you testing it via the route you have posted? What happens when you visit that uri? Is there any middleware or processing which causes a redirect or reload, for example?

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper yes I am testing this. nothing happens when is visit this uri. there is no middleware. I created this test route just for test this. problem persist on other situations.

Comment: @JamesClarkDeveloper turns out chrome extensions can load a page twice! fortunately problem solved using incognito mode.

Comment: Glad you figured it out!